# CSS Transition of background-color

Tags: html, css, transition

I have an some images with hover effects, for example they change the bgcolor of the body.
I want a transition bewtween the colors, but i'm too dumb.
I'm trying to use this, but it still does not show a transition.

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not dumb! Just need some practice. What you have is fine I just can't see the rest of your code. But this is what you're looking for:

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: He said image;hover are changing background of body . Can we do that in css ? How?

Comment: it's not necessary to write `background-color` into the `transition` value (see my snippet below)

Comment: No it's not, but sometimes you want to be specific, as other values could be changing on hover that don't need a transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```css
.x {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background-color: #fa0;
transition: 1000ms linear;
}
.x:hover {
background-color: #0af;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

The important thing is to put the `transition` parameter into the rule for the element itself, and not to write the `background-color` into the `transition` value. The hover rule only defines the second color for the transition.